# Change the executing path of external process

Tags: jscript, wsh

I have an external application that is run through a jscript (with cscript).
The problem is that this external app reads its cfg from its executing path. For example if I click the exe it might be c:\program\myapp.

But whenever I run the program through my jscript its executable path gets set to c:\ so it can't find its config files. This program is so called "portable" so it has no registry entries to go by to find its own location.

Is there anyway through a script to start an application and still maintain its real path and not the scriptengines path?

Regards

Jonas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this article:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/02/01/how-can-i-change-the-working-folder-of-a-script.aspx

The sample code is in VBScript, but it's easy enough to translate to JScript.

The first key is to use the `CurrentDirectory` property of the [`WshShell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aew9yb99%28VS.84%29.aspx) object:

```
var objShell = new ActiveXObject("Wscript.Shell");
objShell.CurrentDirectory = "C:\\Windows";
```

The second key is to extract the directory name for the executable.  The article does this by splitting the path, but I prefer to use [`FileSystemObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ty6h50%28VS.84%29.aspx):

```
var programPath = "C:\\MyApp\\myapp.exe";

var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var programDir = fso.GetParentFolderName(programPath);

WScript.Echo(programDir); // C:\MyApp
```

Comment: All I really needed to know about was seting the "CurrentDirectory" so thanks =)